# Nokia/Sony Ericsson 3.5 headphone on Toshiba PC

Tags: audio, headphones, audio-streaming, digital-audio, headphone-jack

I've a Sony Ericsson headphone, when I put it on a acer PC, it work nice, the stereo and all. But when I put it on a Toshiba PC (I've test this in 4 different model), If you half plug it, you get a weird mono sound, if you completely plug it the sound is just not normal.

So, Is their some kind of software that can change this to make it normal like the one that give you option to make it mono or change the stereo polarity :/

Comment: What do you mean by "just not normal"? Anyway, looks like all 3 components of the connector i.e. [TRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29) are not making contact properly, which is why you're having this problem. If fiddling with the connector doesn't help, guess it's a hardware issue with the jack. Not sure if it can be easily replaced though.

Comment: yeah thank you, it's a hardware issue for sure, I was just wondering if there was a workaround for this issue

Comment: I doubt a software workaround exists, and anyway we don't know what "not normal" sounds like to you. You can use a pair of Bluetooth stereo headphones I guess.

Comment: Thank you, but i think this picture help me to better understand the blem http://bit.ly/1asHSRM